# Using cURL to log in to a website no longer works after hosting change

Tags: php, curl

I have made a PHP curl script that logs into my server from my website it all worked fine until today i changed my hosting and bought a VPS i configured it to use kloxo panel and started propagating my domain.

In the meantime i am uploading my script and browsing to my ip and every thing works fine until i reach my second part of script and it does not get past it login command. i have a feeling something in the php.ini is stopping me

Here's my php.ini can any one help

```
[PHP]
; Kloxo - filecore php.ini for lxphp
engine = On
zend.ze1_compatibility_mode = Off
short_open_tag = On
asp_tags = Off
precision    =  14
y2k_compliance = On
zlib.output_compression = off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func=
serialize_precision = 100
allow_call_time_pass_reference = Off
safe_mode = Off
safe_mode_gid = Off
safe_mode_include_dir =
safe_mode_exec_dir =
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
disable_functions =
disable_classes =
expose_php = Off
max_execution_time = 3000000
max_input_time = 60000
memory_limit = 80000M
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
error_log = /usr/local/lxlabs/ext/php/error.log
variables_order = "GPCS"
register_globals = Off
register_long_arrays = Off
register_argc_argv = Off
post_max_size = 200M
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_charset = "utf-8"
include_path = ".:/php/includes"
user_dir =
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lxlabs/ext/php/lib/"
enable_dl = On
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 200M
allow_url_fopen = On
default_socket_timeout = 6000000000
extension=mysql.so
extension=mbstring.so
[Syslog]
define_syslog_variables  = Off
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off
[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
[MySQL]
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port =
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off
[MySQLI]
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_password =
mysqli.reconnect = Off
[mSQL]
msql.allow_persistent = On
msql.max_persistent = -1
msql.max_links = -1
[PostgresSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0
[Sybase]
sybase.allow_persistent = On
sybase.max_persistent = -1
sybase.max_links = -1
sybase.min_error_severity = 10
sybase.min_message_severity = 10
sybase.compatability_mode = Off
[Sybase-CT]
sybct.allow_persistent = On
sybct.max_persistent = -1
sybct.max_links = -1
sybct.min_server_severity = 10
sybct.min_client_severity = 10
[dbx]
dbx.colnames_case = "lowercase"
[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0
[browscap]
[Informix]
ifx.default_host =
ifx.default_user =
ifx.default_password =
ifx.allow_persistent = On
ifx.max_persistent = -1
ifx.max_links = -1
ifx.textasvarchar = 0
ifx.byteasvarchar = 0
ifx.charasvarchar = 0
ifx.blobinfile = 0
ifx.nullformat = 0
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.use_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor     = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = 0
session.bug_compat_warn = 1
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.entropy_file =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
[MSSQL]
mssql.allow_persistent = On
mssql.max_persistent = -1
mssql.max_links = -1
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
mssql.min_message_severity = 10
mssql.compatability_mode = Off
mssql.secure_connection = Off
[Assertion]
[Ingres II]
ingres.allow_persistent = On
ingres.max_persistent = -1
ingres.max_links = -1
ingres.default_database =
ingres.default_user =
ingres.default_password =
[Verisign Payflow Pro]
pfpro.defaulthost = "test-payflow.verisign.com"
pfpro.defaultport = 443
pfpro.defaulttimeout = 30
[Sockets]
sockets.use_system_read = On
[com]
[mbstring]
[FrontBase]
[exif]
[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off
[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
;zend_optimizer.optimization_level=15
;zend_optimizer.disable_licensing = 1
;zend_extension_manager.optimizer=/usr/local/lxlabs/ext/lib/Zend/lib/Optimizer-2.5.7
;zend_extension_manager.optimizer_ts=/usr/local/lxlabs/ext/lib/Zend/lib/Optimizer_TS-2.5.7
;zend_extension=/usr/local/lxlabs/ext/lib/Zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so
;zend_extension_ts=/usr/local/lxlabs/ext/lib/Zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager_TS.so
; Local Variables:
; tab-width: 4
; End:
```

Comment: Can we see just the relevant part of the second part of your script? It's not clear what you are doing with `cURL` at the moment. (By the way, if you write using initial capital letters, and split prose into sentences and paragraphs, then you'll be less likely to be downvoted, and thus more likely to get useful answers. Just so you know!)

Comment: no this is my php ini file any php script or curl script i run just does not work checkout http://5.39.118.103/icheck.php i know that wrks as i have it on a shared host

Comment: What does "does not work" mean exactly?

Comment: when i use the script and click subit (this is on any of my php scripts) it doeas nothing at all

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Run a page with a phpinfo call on it. Should confirm if curl is loaded and give you a starting point to research the bug. I'm not seeing the curl extension in the INI file.